# Properly use main function arguments in C, NetBeans 7.2

Tags: c, file, netbeans-7, program-entry-point, ubuntu-13.10

I'm having a hard time trying to pass a directory path to my program on NetBeans 7.2, what I tried to do was to write `"${OUTPUT_PATH}" "/home/vitor/Área de Trabalho/Programação/Teste"` on the project's parameters. `/home/vitor/Área de Trabalho/Programação/Teste` is my directory's path, I have 3 `.txt` files inside it, and my program is supposed to read each one of them by adding their names in the path's ending, something like:

`/home/vitor/Área de Trabalho/Programação/Teste/times.txt`

Here is my piece of code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
if(argc == 1){
    printf("ERROR: The directory's path wasn't informed.");
    exit(1);
}
else{
    char endtimes[200];
    strcpy(endtimes, argv[1]);
    strcat(endtimes, "times.txt");
    }    
FILE *caminho;
caminho = fopen(endtimes, "r");
if (!caminho){
    printf("Error trying to open file.");
    exit(1);
}
```

Everytime I try to run the code, it displays `Error trying to open file.` I checked argc and it's value is 4 (which I guess is not right.) I don't have enough experience using netbeans, in fact, this is my first program to work with files. So, could you guys help me?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.

Thanks for your patience.

--EDIT--

I made changes on the project's parameters according to the comments below, `endtimes` is storing the correct file path : `/home/vitor/Área de Trabalho/Programação/Teste/times.txt` but I still get `Error trying to open file.` Should the file path be different because I'm using Ubuntu 13?

Comment: `argv[]` is indexed from 0, starting with the process argument, then the first command-line argument at **1**. What are all those **2** s doing in there? The valid range is `0...(argc-1)` And does the path you're using already exist? `fopen` isn't going to create it for you.

Comment: After this line `strcpy(endjogos, argv[2]);`, add this: `printf(argv[2]);`. Your pathname has embedded spaces and most likely you will need to enclose the path in single or double quotes. The print statement will let you know what path is actually being used.

Comment: you fundamentally changed it with that edit. Which is your *real* code ?

Comment: I concur with David (+1). If you have long file names with embedded spaces, you need to dbl-quote the name when presented as an arg.

Comment: The program is just supposed to add the filenames `times.txt`,`jogos.txt` and `apostas.txt` at the end of the directory's path, so, for example, `endjogos` would be something like this `/home/vitor/Área de Trabalho/Programação/Teste/jogos.txt`

Comment: As per earlier suggestion `printf` your path to see what is going on. Also if you append `"jogos.txt"` to `"...Teste"`, you are getting `"...Testejogos.txt"` which is missing `'/'` between file and directory name.

Comment: Thanks, for noticing the missing `/`, made the changes and posted on the EDIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argv[0]` is the executable's name and if you've passed 3 arguments in the form of filenames, those will be stored in `argv[1]`, `argv[2]` and `argv[3]`, respectively. So you might want something like:

```
strcpy(endjogos, argv[1]);
strcat(endjogos, "jogos.txt");
strcpy(endtimes, argv[2]);
strcat(endtimes, "times.txt");
strcpy(endapost, argv[3]);
strcat(endapost, "apostas.txt");
```

Note that C arrays are zero-indexed, so with argc==4, you have `argv[0]`, `argv[1]`, `argv[2]`, `argv[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a program call like this "main.out -one.txt -two.txt tree.txt" you have 4 parameters. Therefore`argc` will be 4
`argv[0]` will be "main.out"
`argv[1]` will be "one.txt"
`argv[2]` will be "two.txt"
`argv[3]` will be "tree.txt"